# Some questions about this bar graph code

Tags: c#, charts

Below is the code for a bar graph using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting that I got from the Web. The problem is that I don't understand several parts of it and I'm at a loss as to where to find a good resource to learn about all the ins and outs of using all of the charting stuff.  Isn't there some 3rd party book available?  Normally Microsoft provides example code for how to use the various classes and members but when it comes to charting I can't find anything other than a few random and unexplained 3rd party examples on the Web.

Anyway, below is the code and the graph it produces follows it.  I have the following questions...

1. Why are two of the bars to the left of the 1 on the X axis and the other two to the right of it?  What controls this and how do I make them start at 0?
2. What controls the width of the bars?
3. How do I remove all labels along the X axis (the 0, 1, and 2)?

About all I do understand about the results I'm seeing is why there are 4 bars and why their Y-values are 2, 1, 7, and 5.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
     System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
     System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

     chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
     chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
     chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
     chart1.Name = "chart1";
     series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
     series1.Name = "Series1";
     chart1.Series.Add(series1);
     chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 400);
     chart1.TabIndex = 0;
     chart1.Text = "chart1";
     this.Controls.Add(chart1);

     string[] seriesArray = { "Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Monkey" };
     int[] pointsArray = { 2, 1, 7, 5 };
     for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
     {
        Series series = chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);
        series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
     }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1. All your datapoints are added without a valid x-value so by default they are added 'indexed' and placed at `1` . You can change that by  adding them with a valid x-value of your choice; use the AddXY method for this. (Recommended). All datapoints sit at the same spot, so they are grouped to avoid overlapping the various series

Note however that as long as there is only **one** `DataPoint` in each `Series` the points will still be shown a `1` even if you add them with a valid numeric x-values:

```
series.Points.AddXY(0, pointsArray[i]);  // <- this creates a valid x-value of you choosing
```

To move them to the proper position you will need to add at least one more point to at least one series, even if it is only a dummy:

```
 chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 0);
```

Note further that you can't really move the column group flush to the y-axis as it always wants to be  centered around some `DataPoint`. So you would have to calculate the total width of the group and then use half of it as the `Minimum` x-value to display; but this will be a rather complex calculation involving `ChartArea` percentage etc. Not recommended.. You may be fine with some trial and error..:

```
chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum = -0.25;
```

2. Use this special string property `PixelPointWidth` to control the bar or column width:

   `foreach (Series s in chart1.Series) s["PixelPointWidth"] = "100";`
3. To turn off axis labelling use this:

   `chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;`

Final note: since you mentioned that you are new to `Charts` let me just say that more often you will have only **one series with many points** than **several series with only one point** as you have created. But as it stands it is fine, one series for each category and your categries are the animals.

But imagine some other animal statistics like *weight, price, age, speed* etc..

Now you might want to use these as the categories and add one data point for each animal..

Comment: Thanks for taking all the time it must have taken to provide such a detailed and thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code will do what you expected. Your created a new series for each animal so you get four series with one data point and the chart tries to group all values on data point "1".

```
string[] seriesArray = { "Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Monkey" };
Series series = chart1.Series.Add("Animals");
int[] pointsArray = { 2, 1, 7, 5 };
for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
{
    DataPoint point = series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
    point.AxisLabel = seriesArray[i];
}
```